# Centralised login system to redirect

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, database-design, multi-tenant

[image: server architecture]

I have a web app which I need to duplicate for multiple clients.

Each client will have his own server space and a database.

Each database will have one user table per client and they have independent data from each others.

Clients could access to their site via sub-domain URLs.
One client's URL may look like this ex: www.abcgroup.example.com (client: abcgroup)

I want to have one centralized login page at www.example.com/login.

Once a client login, he will be redirected to abcgroup.example.com automatically, without having to type his own sub-domain URL. 
ex:This site managed to do it https://tictail.com/

Problem is that I have multiple databases with multiple user tables. So how can I authenticate users globally from one login page?

I'm not sure whether I have to check against all the user tables in client databases.

Do I need to read from all the user tables? (I'm using Codeigniter 2)

Thanks!

Comment: you should have atleast user table in one single database so that you can make login and than redirect

Comment: Please check the update. thanks

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to do this:

1. Have a central DB that has all the users. This makes sure all the users are unique. Having multiple DBs, you may run into duplicate users.
2. Making the user select or type in the subdomain in the login page. Some web apps do this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment komirad. The reason I have multiple databases is that I need to isolate data from one another. I can't have one database for all the clients architecture as its too complicated for us to manage. Is there any workaround with this implementation, so I can redirect from one login page?

Comment: You can either clone the users to a single DB. Moving forward, uniqueness validation should be queried against this DB.

Or you can have a separate "product owner" accounts which they use to manage their "subscription" with you. (That's how atlassian/jira handles it) I don't think there's a scalable solution to query multiple databases.